# How can I call a SOAP 1.2 Web service from a LotusScript agent?

Tags: web-services, soap, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm using a Lotus Domino 9 on a windows Server

I must call a **Soap 1.2** web service that is not maintained anymore

The Lotus **Web service consumers** only accepts **Soap 1.1** web services, So I cannot use this nice feature to bind my web services.

Is it possible to call a **Soap 1.2** web service from my **LotusScript** agent and if yes, what are the needed steps ?

Comment: did you read http://blog.redturtle.it/2013/12/04/integration-between-axis2-and-xpages

Comment: Yes I did, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution using the `XMLHTTP` object

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim xmlhttp As Variant
    dim DOMDocument As Variant
    Dim soapEnvelope As String
    Dim webService As String
    dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim strxml As String

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    Set DOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    webService = "http://server/path/service"

    username = "user1"
    password = "123456"

    soapEnvelope ={<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:doc="http://checkYourOwnEnvelopeDetails.com">}
    soapEnvelope =soapEnvelope & {<soap:Header/>}
    soapEnvelope =soapEnvelope & {<soap:Body>}

    ' ...use SoapUI to know the exact envelop structure

    soapEnvelope =soapEnvelope & {</soap:Body>}
    soapEnvelope =soapEnvelope & {</soap:Envelope>}

    DOMDocument.loadXML (soapEnvelope)

    Call xmlhttp.open("POST", webService, False,username,password)
    Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8")
    Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Username", username)
    Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Password", password)

    ' again, use SoapUI to discover the exact name of the action
    Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:getListAll")
    Call xmlhttp.send(DOMDocument.xml)
    strxml = xmlhttp.responseText

    ...    
End Sub
```