# SOAP header for authentication in Notes/Domino

Tags: soap, lotus-domino, ws-security, lotusscript

I need to consume a WS that requires client (machine) certificate. More precisely it uses WS-Security : SOAP Message Security, WS-Security : X.509 Certificate Token Profile as defined by http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/os/wss-SOAPMessageSecurity-v1.1.1-os.html

Using the native consumer, Domino don't add (magically) the authentication in the SOAP header. Now how I'm supposed to do add the security in header? Ideally in LotusScript... 
I don't see anyway to embed the Consumer in my own header or enrich the existing consumer. I join the IBM response on this.

So my question:

- Is there a work around to do this in Lotusscript ?
- did some of you done something like this in java (and I will probably make an LS2J since a lot of LotusScript code already exists when I will get (hopefully) the response from the WS

IBM response:

*We understand that you are attempting to use SOAP header for authentication. Unfortunately this is currently not supported.
For your reference, we have at least two Enhancement Requests (that I could find in this area) that are related to this topic:

SPR # SODY9H6BTM: Creating Your Own Soap Objects Does Not Support Client Certificate Authentication In A Web Agent.

SPR # JSHN7A3MLP: Authentication data in the Header element of WS Consumer SOAP envelopes
Unfortunately there is nothing further we can do in Support at this time.*

Comment: It worked for me to use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580457/how-can-i-call-a-soap-1-2-web-service-from-a-lotusscript-agent/41848253#41848253

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your problem correctly you do not know how to deal with SOAP header and if so there are 2 things you may want to know:

1) Passing session using native Domino consumer approach. See example below

```
TestServiceLocator service = new TestServiceLocator();
TestPort port = service.getTestPort();
// that would tell to save cookie session between calls
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)port)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, Boolean.TRUE);
```

2) If it does not work for you, you may try to use native SOAP approach. I've blogged about that recently: [SOAP and passing session](http://dpastov.blogspot.com/2016/01/soap-and-passing-session.html)

```
// Create SOAP Connection  
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();  
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();  
// connect to webserivce
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(connect(username, password), url);

// read cookie from response and use it when send another requests
MimeHeaders session = soapResponse.getMimeHeaders(); 
String sesisonCookie = session.getHeader("Set-Cookie")[0];

SOAPMessage soapResponse2 = soapConnection.call(customerGetAll(sesisonCookie), url);
soapConnection.close();
```

and than imagine you are in **customGetAll** method

```
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("Customer_GetAll", "m");
soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Cookie", sesisonCookie);
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

Hope it will help.