# Domino client web services and SOAP 1.2

Tags: soap, web, service, cxf, lotus-domino

I create a client in Domino to consume a web service that works with SOAP 1.2 and has HTTPBinding.
The client generation tool for Domino Designer Web services an error is displayed when trying to generate reporting that the SOAP accepted version is 1.1.

I decided to create the client with CXF framework through tool wsdl2java. In an agent I used these classes to consume the web service, however the below error was displayed. I think it's because of the SOAP version, but I'm not sure.

com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.MUTube getMisUnderstoodHeaders
INFO: Element not understood={http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action

Also generated a jar of classes generated by wsdltojava and imported to another agent, but the error below is displayed.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=, offset=6

The question is, no way consume a web service with SOAP 1.2 in Domino only supports up to version 1.1?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there is no way to natively consume a web service with soap version 1.2. There are already several requests from IBM to upgrade the SOAP version. What I did, was to develop a new layer through a new web service with the version SOAP 1.1, which internally calls the web service with the SOAP version 1.2;

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Domino's web service consumer supports SOAP 1.2 at this time. You might be able to do what you need with an agent though - here's one way: [How can I call a SOAP 1.2 Web service from a LotusScript agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580457/how-can-i-call-a-soap-1-2-web-service-from-a-lotusscript-agent)